# Is there a way to generate a dataframe consisting of elements in a list within a list using lapply?

Tags: r

I would like to index a vector inside a list within a list, and generate a new dataframe that contains that specific vector in each of the lists in every row. I was previously considering using a for loop to do so

```
a = list(odds = c(1,3,5,7), evens = c(2,4,6,8), name = "name1")
b = list(odds = c(9,11,13,15), evens = c(10,12,14,16), name = "name2")
c = list(odds = c(17,19,21,23), evens = c(18,20,22,24), name = "name3")

d = list(a,b,c)

output = data.frame()
for (i in 1:length(d)) {
output <- rbind(output, d[[i]]$odds)
}
```

The expected output is as such

```
#   X1 X3 X5 X7  
# 1  1  3  5  7  
# 2  9 11 13 15  
# 3 17 19 21 23
```

However, as I perpetually require to do such indexing when I handle data, I was wondering if there was a less convoluted method of doing this. Is there perhaps a cleaner method using `lapply` and `rbind` functions to avoid looping? I could not figure out how to index the vector required.

Apologies if the question is poorly formatted, this is my first time posting on a coding forum.

Answer (score 3):

You can use :

```
res <- data.frame(t(sapply(d, `[[`, 'odds')))

#  X1 X2 X3 X4
#1  1  3  5  7
#2  9 11 13 15
#3 17 19 21 23
```

Comment: Hi Ronak,

Unfortunately, the lists I'm actually working with have many other components other than vectors, so I cannot just collapse the lists into a data.frame.

Comment: @timetoimprove123 Can you edit your post to include the expected output for the data shared?

Comment: I've edited the post to also include an additional list element that is present in my datasets

Answer (score 3):

This can also be used, albeit very similar to the one posted by dear @akrun. `map` family of functions also accept integer or character vector in place of anonymous function or formula. In that case it serves as an extractor function by index(integer) or name (character). Then it calls internally to `pluck` as specified by @akrun's solution. You can verify it by `as_mapper("odds")`.

```
library(purrr)

# We use big bang operator to splice the list of arguments and then
# use exec to apply `rbind` function to the spliced list.

exec(rbind, !!!map(d, "odds"))

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    3    5    7
[2,]    9   11   13   15
[3,]   17   19   21   23
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
d %>% 
  transpose %>%
  pluck('odds') %>%
  invoke(rbind, .)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    3    5    7
#[2,]    9   11   13   15
#[3,]   17   19   21   23
```

Answer (score 2):

Another base R option using `simplify2array`

```
> t(do.call(cbind, simplify2array(d)["odds", ]))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    3    5    7
[2,]    9   11   13   15
[3,]   17   19   21   23
```