# Delete lagging text in one column after matching a pre-specified string in another column R

Tags: r

I thought I had a simple task in front of me and I ended up stumped. Let's say I have the following data frame:

```
JobDF <- data.frame (occupation  = c("Frank is a teacher for preschoolers","Jane is a doctor, and a good one","John cooks part-time"), abridged = c("a teacher", "and a","cooks part"))
```

My goal is to delete all of the text in JobDF$occupation after reaching the end of a pattern match in JobDF$abridged. The pattern in JobDF$abridged only appears in JobDF$occupation once. My intended output is this:

```
JobDF

occupation            abridged
Frank is a teacher    a teacher
Jane is a doctor      and a
John cooks part       cooks part
```

I don't think I can use *sub* or *grepl* because I don't have a) regular patterns in my data, or b) the deletion wouldn't happen at a regularly specified numerical placement. %in% would result in exactly matching columns. Does anyone know how I might go about solving this problem? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `stringr::str_remove` which is vectorised :

```
JobDF$occupation <- stringr::str_remove(JobDF$occupation, 
                    sprintf('(?<=%s).*', JobDF$abridged))

JobDF

#               occupation   abridged
#1      Frank is a teacher  a teacher
#2 Jane is a doctor, and a      and a
#3         John cooks part cooks part
```

In base R, you can use `mapply` :

```
delete_content <- function(x, y) {
  sub(sprintf('(?<=%s).*', x), '', y, perl = TRUE)  
}
JobDF$occupation <- mapply(delete_content, JobDF$abridged, JobDF$occupation)
```

Comment: Thank you for providing multiple solutions! Both worked perfectly in my dataset, and I certainly learned some new approaches using R. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `tidyverse` approach

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
JobDF %>%
     mutate(occupation = str_replace(occupation, 
             glue::glue('^(.*{abridged}).*'), '\\1'))
#               occupation   abridged
#1      Frank is a teacher  a teacher
#2 Jane is a doctor, and a      and a
#3         John cooks part cooks part
```

Comment: This is an incredibly concise solution! Thank you for showing me this method, akrun.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this maybe not as brilliant as the ones proposed before by great contributors of R. It may sound a bit verbose but it is the first time I'm using `str_locate` and I really liked it:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

map2(JobDF$occupation, JobDF$abridged, ~ str_locate(.x, .y)) %>%
  exec(rbind, !!!.) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>%
  bind_cols(JobDF) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(occupation = map_chr(end, ~ str_sub(occupation, 1L, .x))) %>%
  select(-c(1, 2))


# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Rowwise: 
  occupation              abridged  
  <chr>                   <chr>     
1 Frank is a teacher      a teacher 
2 Jane is a doctor, and a and a     
3 John cooks part         cooks part
```

**Special thanks** to dear @akrun for his ever insightful recommendations, we can make this a little more simple.

```
map2(JobDF$occupation, JobDF$abridged, ~ str_locate(.x, .y) %>% as_tibble) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  bind_cols(JobDF) %>%
  mutate(occupation = str_sub(occupation, 1L, end)) %>%
  select(-c(1, 2))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You are quite right. I was grappling with the issue of `row_bind`ing unnamed vectors with no avails. But your solution makes my code a little less complicated.

Comment: Just a quick comment `%>%bind_cols(JobDF)%>% mutate(occupation = str_sub(occupation, 1, end))` should work too as `str_sub` is vectorized

Comment: You are absolutely right. Sometimes I just tend to choose the hardest way of writing codes. By the way the reason I asked this was for this question I could not get it done as you mentioned about unnamed vectors:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67531553/is-there-a-way-to-generate-a-dataframe-consisting-of-elements-in-a-list-within-a/67539822#67539822

Comment: Dear Anoushiravan R, I understand.  With `rbind`, there are muliple methods available i.e. `methods('rbind')` so it will be triggered based on the class of the incoming object i.e. if the input is a matrix rbind.matrix will be called

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. I honestly didn't want to take your time this much. But I really appreciate that.

Comment: Well I see this as a brilliant contribution too! Thank you for your help. I'm glad you were able to apply a new skill, too.